# How to read HTTP-Header status code of client URL by using ASP.Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

I need to read status (403 or 404) of HTTP-header when read a URL by using C# in ASP.Net. For example:
URL1: https://www.instagram.com/khaniki.ah
URL2: https://www.instagram.com/khaniki.ah123456
I get status 200 (HttpStatusCode.Found) when I try to read URL1 and same for reading URL2 while it's not exist; See more in photos.

Also, I use this following code:

```
    var Url = UrlTbx.Text;
    Uri urlCheck = new Uri(Url);

    HttpWebRequest HttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    HttpRequest.Timeout = 15000;
    HttpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    HttpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    HttpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //HttpRequest.Method = "GET";
    HttpRequest.Method = "HEAD";//both methods was tested
    HttpWebResponse HttpResponse;

    try
    {
        HttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpRequest.GetResponse();

        if (HttpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
            Lit.Text = "YES" + " / " + HttpResponse.StatusCode;
        else if (HttpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            Lit.Text = "NO" + " / " + HttpResponse.StatusCode;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return false;
    }
```

[image: URL1]
[image: URL2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server you're requesting doesn't seem to accept HEAD requests. Try to keep the GET header method and try to remove

```
HttpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Also Found is not 200. You're talking about HttpStatusCode.OK for 200. 
I get the 404 you're looking for when doing simply

```
   var Url = "https://www.instagram.com/khaniki.ah123456/";
   Uri urlCheck = new Uri(Url);

   HttpWebRequest HttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

   HttpRequest.Method = "Get";

   var dHttpWebResponse = await HttpRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

or try with the httpclient api, (to avoid the exception)

```
var Url = "https://www.instagram.com/khaniki.ah123456/";
        Uri urlCheck = new Uri(Url);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var res = client.GetAsync(urlCheck).Result;
        var statusCode = res.StatusCode; //should be 404
```

Comment: I also used Get method

Comment: I tested your opinion but I cannot find or get status 400 in header. See response "Pragma : no-cache 
Vary : Accept-Language 
Content-Language : en 
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=86400 
Connection : keep-alive 
Content-Length : 0 
Cache-Control : private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate 
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8 
Date : Thu, 27 Jul 2017 10:58:20 GMT 
Expires : Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT 
Location : https://www.instagram.com/khaniki.ah123456/"

Comment: I updated my answer, with httpclient class you should have a 404 instead of an exception

Comment: It works and tank you! Is there any other solution or suggestion that return code?

Comment: I don"t understand , what do you want ? another solution ? if you want to stick with the WebRequest one, you have to catch the WebException and read the status code inside it...  if it's ok then you can mark this as answered by checking it.

Comment: I used WebException and get the .response object from there. Thanks for the hint @kitAndKat